# Is polycarbonate resistant to extremely cold temperatures?

Tags: polymers, materials

I am working on a project which involves the use of polycarbonate. Polycarbonate is quite a new material to me as I haven't worked with it yet. I want to know its characteristics in detail, as it would help me in my project. Here they go:

1. Is polycarbonate strong enough to withstand pressures up to 20 atm? If the surface has a slight curvature, can it retain the curvature under such high pressures?
2. Is polycarbonate resistant to inhospitable temperatures as low as -200˚C?

Comment: Being "resistant" or "strong enough" is quite not clear. Then again, I doubt PC is right pick for whatever you want to do.

Comment: "withstand pressures up to 20 atm?" Certainly -- in a thick enough piece. You need to be more specific, and do some research. Polycarbonate cryogenic supplies are sold (e.g., https://www.grainger.com/category/lab-supplies/lab-diagnostics/cryogenic-supplies?attrs=Material|Polycarbonate&filters=attrs), so consult the literature and manufacturer for specs.